# Why Do Inline Block Divs Behave Differently From Inline Block Buttons?

Tags: html, css

I tried to change the y-height of an inline button and realized that it doesn't work by setting a negative margin (transform would work though).  Choosing a div instead of a button works, also wrapping the div inside a button.  Where does this difference come from?  I guess it has to do with baseline?

```css
div, button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
.inline-offset {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
Hello,<br />
dear
<div class="inline-offset"></div>
<br />
world!
<br />
<br />
Hello,<br />
dear
<button class="inline-offset"></button>
<br />
world!
<br />
<br />
Hello,<br />
dear
<button><div class="inline-offset"></div></button>
<br />
world!
```

[EDIT] Just in case it appears differently in some browsers, here's  what it looks like to me.  Second box is positioned as if no margin was present.

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to achieve here. Have you tried setting base line? Also it's possible because element is block

Comment: I want to adjust the y-height of the element.  I succeeded by wrapping the div inside the button, but I'm just curious and want to understand CSS better.  Whenevere an element is behaving differently from what I expected, I want to understand where my assumptions went wrong.

Comment: Three elements looks similar what am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe it's browser dependent?  [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/JACD1cE.png) what it looks like to me.  The first and third box is positioned lower, the second box is positioned as it would be without margin.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I learned that whenever you set `display: inline` or `inline-block` you must be careful about any spaces or newlines that exist in front of the element.

I will be honest in saying that I don't know yet any official documentation about this behavior, but we all would appreciate any help to clarify it.

```css
div, button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
.inline-offset {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
Hello,<br />
dear <!--
--><div class="inline-offset"></div>
<br />
world!
<br />
<br />
Hello,<br />
dear <!--
--><button class="inline-offset"></button>
<br />
world!
<br />
<br />
Hello,<br />
dear <!--
--><button><div class="inline-offset"></div></button>
<br />
world!
```

Comment: what question are you answering?